# biber cannot find global bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

Using MikTeX for Linux, Ubuntu, and LuaLaTeX.
bib file "Références.bib" is located in `~/texmf/bibtex/bib/Références/` with `~/texmf` added as a root in MikTeX Console.
tex file ("a" is not a valid reference, but I'd recognize the error):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Références.bib}

\begin{document}
 \cite{a}
\end{document}
```

biblatex output:

```
*****
*****     Biber output: 
*****     cd "/home/ubuntu/yann/Documents/Scolaire/1A/Stage/Rapport stage/Présentation rapport"
*****     biber test
*****
INFO - This is Biber 2.15
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Références.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'Références.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

biber works when the bibliography is put in the same directory.
What would be the correct thing to put in `\addbibresource`?

Comment: your path should work. Update the file name database (in the miktex console, menu tasks). If it doesn't help, try to rename your file so that it doesn't use accented chars - while it theoretically should work, practically it sometimes fails.

Comment: Removed all non-ASCII chars (even spaces in paths), updated the file name database (Tasks -> Refresh file name database) and nothing changed

Comment: hm, try to put in a subfolder of bibtex/bib, e.g. `bibtex/bib/mybib`. Btw are you sure that the texmf it found? Do tex files in tex/latex there works?

Comment: bib file is already `texmf/bibtex/bib/References/References.bib`. Plus I forgot to mention that `kpsewhich References.bib` does find it (but not "References")

Comment: On Windows 10 my MikTeX-installed Biber has issues finding `Références.bib` when searching via `kpsewhich` but not when searching locally. A non-ASCII file name like `references.bib` works well in both cases. Please update your question with what exactly you did with `References.bib` (i.e. the non-ASCII version) and the exact error messages you get.

Comment: I renamed all folders to remove non-ASCII characters and spaces, I removed all non-ASCII characters from `References.bib`. Error log is the same :  
`INFO - This is Biber 2.15   
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'   
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'   
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0   
INFO - Processing section 0   
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'References.bib' for section 0   
ERROR - Cannot find 'References.bib'!   
INFO - ERRORS: 1   
`

Comment: And `kpsewhich References.bib` finds the file? Do things work if you cite `sigfridsson` from `biblatex-examples.bib`? That file is also searched and found via `kpsewhich`.